# Python Dataframe: Different RMSE Score Every Time I Run Random Forest Regressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, modeling, seed

I currently run a random forest model using the following code.  I set a random_state equal to 100.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

X_train_RIA_INST_PWM, X_test_RIA_INST_PWM, y_train_RIA_INST_PWM, y_test_RIA_INST_PWM = train_test_split(X_RIA_INST_PWM, Y_RIA_INST_PWM, test_size=0.3, random_state = 100)



# Random Forest Regressor for RIA_INST_PWM accounts  

import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

regressor_RIA_INST_PWM = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, min_samples_split = 10)
regressor_RIA_INST_PWM.fit(X_RIA_INST_PWM, Y_RIA_INST_PWM)

print ("R^2 for training set:"),
print (regressor_RIA_INST_PWM.score(X_train_RIA_INST_PWM, y_train_RIA_INST_PWM))

print ('-'*50)

print ("R^2 for test set:"),
print (regressor_RIA_INST_PWM.score(X_test_RIA_INST_PWM, y_test_RIA_INST_PWM))
```

And then I use the following code to calculate the prediction values.

```
def predict_AUM(df, features, regressor):

    # Reset index for later merge of predicted target values with Account IDs
    df.reset_index();

    # Set predictor variables 
    X_Predict = df[features]

    # Clean inputs 
    X_Predict = X_Predict.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
    X_Predict = X_Predict.fillna(0)

    # Predict Current_AUM
    Y_AUM_Snapshot_1yr_Predict = regressor.predict(X_Predict)
    df['PREDICTED_SPAN'] = Y_AUM_Snapshot_1yr_Predict

    return df 

df_EVENT5_20 = predict_AUM(df_EVENT5_19, dfzip_features_AUM_RIA_INST_PWM, regressor_RIA_INST_PWM)
```

Finally, I calculate the RMSE of my results:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(df_EVENT5_20['SPAN_DAYS'], df_EVENT5_20['PREDICTED_SPAN']))
rmse
```

Each time I run my code ... my RMSE changes.  It has varied from 7.75 to 16.4  Why is this happening? And how can I have the same RMSE each time I run the code?  Additionally, how do I optimize my model for RMSE?

Comment: Did you get back to trying my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You only seeded the train_test_split which makes sure that the random allocation of the data to train and test set is reproducible.

As the name suggests *Random*ForestRegressor also contains parts in the algorithm that rely on random numbers (e.g., specifically different parts of data or different features for training individual decision trees). If you want reproducible results, you need to seed it as well. For that you need to initilize it with random_state like that:

```
regressor_RIA_INST_PWM = RandomForestRegressor(
                           n_estimators=100, 
                           min_samples_split = 10, 
                           random_state=100
                         )
```