# Changing RMSE values while testing an MLP and a LSTM

Tags: python, neural-network, mlp

The RMSE values in my MLP and LSTM model seems to change when tested on the same sample and model again and again. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47896198/python-dataframe-different-rmse-score-every-time-i-run-random-forest-regressor), where adding a random state solved the issue. Is there something like that I could do too?

Sharing my MLP code here:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, input_dim = 10))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1))
opt = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=opt , loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x, y, epochs=250, batch_size = 10 ,verbose=2)
Predicted_values = model.predict(test_x)
RMSE = sqrt(mean_squared_error(test_y,Predicted_values))
print(RMSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix the seed for numpy and tensorflow backend

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(42)

from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(42)
```

For more information on the why, check [this article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/) from machinelearningmastery blog